# Is boxing going to happen here if T is int?

Tags: c#, boxing

```
public static bool Equal<T>(T value, T match) {
           return Equals(value, match);
       }
```

So the question is if T is int32 is there going to be boxing here or the compiler will choose the int32 Equals with no boxing?

Comment: @Rango So there will be boxing? Why you are answering the different question?=)

Comment: @LewsTherin - the signature of `object<equals>` is `bool Equals(object arg1);` which is not the same as the above defined method or the method that code is calling (which happens to be itself).

Comment: The short answer is: overload resolution will choose `public static bool Equals (object objA, object objB);`  The arguments will be ints. Therefore they have to be boxed, because int-to-object is a boxing conversion.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks Eric ;)

Comment: @EricLippert I honestly don't know why my mind jumped to that; I was thinking about it all wrong. I need to learn more about the inner-workings of C#.

Comment: @LewsTherin: If only there were a blog about that... :-)

Comment: You're welcome. To clarify the question, which "int32 equals" did you have in mind?

Comment: Also, maybe say what you're trying to accomplish here. Equality checking is very tricky in C#, and we can probably give you some tips on how to do it correctly if we know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @EricLippert We were just wondering whether there is a chance that some advanced level optimization could be going on here, but everything is working very straightforward.

Comment: Boxing always occurs even if you would use `return value.Equals(match)` because there is no constraint so `object` is assumed. If you'd make a constraint `where T: IEquatable<T>` then boxing can be avoided.

Comment: Intellisense will tell you what overload is being called, and what it's arguments are, although `object.Equals` only has two overloads, and only one with two parameters, so I don't know what method could be called other than the one accepting objects.

Comment: Right, the key thing to realize with generics is that generics are not C++ templates. A C++ template *recompiles all the code for every template specialization at compile time*.  A generic compiles the code *once*, and then *generates optimized versions of that code at runtime*. But the optimized versions do *not* re-do overload resolution. If overload resolution chooses a method that takes `object` because that's the best it can do with an unconstrained `T`, then it will be the `object` version no matter what `T` is at runtime.

Comment: @Servy: I suspect that what the OP was imagining was that the jitter could recognize "Oh, I have a call to Equals that is passing two ints, let me optimize that down to a 32 bit comparison instruction". But that's not what happens.

Comment: @EricLippert The question specifically asks about which overload of equals is chosen, so I don't see a basis for assuming that the OP thought there was some runtime optimization by the JITTer.

Comment: @Servy: The basis is the OP saying "**We were just wondering whether there is a chance that some advanced level optimization could be going on here**". The fundamental question here is whether the boxing is optimized away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There has been some confusion in the comments to the original question and to Rango's (basically correct) answer, so I thought I'd clear those up.

First off, a note about how generics work in C#. Generics are not templates!

In C#, generics are compiled once by the C# compiler into generic IL, and that IL is then recompiled into specialized forms by the jitter. For example, if we have a method `M<T>(T t)`, then the C# compiler will compile that method and its body *once*, into IL.

When the jitter comes along, a call to `M<string>`, `M<object>` or `M<IEnumerable>` will  trigger *exactly one* compilation; the jitter is very clever and it can compile the body into a form where it works no matter what the type argument is, provided that the type argument is a reference type.  But `M<int>` and `M<double>` will each be compiled into their own assembly code body.

Note that the jitter does not know the rules of C#, and C# does overload resolution.  By the time the C# compiler generates the IL, *the exact method for every method call has already been chosen*.  So if you have:

```
static bool X(object a, object b) => object.Equals(a, b);
static bool X(int a, int b) => a == b;
static bool M<T>(T v, T m) => X(v, m);
```

then overload resolution chooses `X(object, object)` and compiles the code as though you wrote:

```
static bool M<T>(T v, T m) => X((object)v, (object)m);
```

If `T` turns out to be `int`, then both `int`s are boxed to `object`.

Let me re-emphasize that. By the time we get to the jitter, we already know which `X` is going to be called; that decision was made at C# compile time. The C# compiler reasons "I've got two Ts, I do not know that they are convertible to int, so I've got to choose the object version".

This is in contrast to C++ template code, which re-compiles the code for each template instantiation, and re-does overload resolution.

So that answers the original question that was asked.

Now let's get into the weird details.

> When jit compiling `M<int>`, is the jitter permitted to notice that `M<int>` calls `X(object, object)`, which then calls `object.Equals(object, object)`, which is known to compare two boxed ints for equality, and generate the code directly that compares the two ints in their unboxed form?

Yes, the jitter is *permitted* to perform that optimization.

> Does it in practice perform that optimization?

Not to my knowledge. The jitter does perform some inlining optimizations, but to my knowledge it does not perform any inlinings that advanced.

> Are there situations in which the jitter does in practice elide a boxing?

Yes!

> Can you give some examples?

Sure thing. Consider the following *terrible* code:

```
struct S 
{
  public int x;
  public void M()
  {
      this.x += 1;
  }
}
```

When we do:

```
S s = whatever;
s.M();
```

What happens?  `this` in a value type is equivalent to a parameter of type `ref S`. So we take a ref to `s`, pass it to `M`, and so on.

Now consider the following:

```
interface I
{
  void M();
}
struct S : I { /* body as before */ }
```

Now suppose we do this:

```
S s = whatever;
I i = s;
i.M();
```

What happens?

- Converting `s` to `I` is a boxing conversion, so we allocate a box, make the box implement `I`, and make a copy of `s` in the box.
- Calling `i.M()` passes the box as the receiver to the implementation of `I` in the box. That then takes a ref to the copy of `s` in the box, and passes that ref as the `this` to `M`.

All right, now comes the bit that will confuse the heck out of you.

```
void Q<T>(T t) where T : I
{
  t.M();
}
...
S s = whatever;
Q<S>(s);
```

Now what happens? Obviously we make a copy of `s` into `t` and there is no boxing; both are of type `S`.  But: `I.M` is expecting a receiver of type `I`, and `t` is of type `S`.  Do we have to do what we did before?  Do we box `t` to a box that implements `I`, and then the box calls `S.M` with the `this` being a ref to the box?

No.  The jitter generates code that elides the boxing and calls `S.M` directly with `ref t` as `this`.

What does this mean?  This means that:

```
void Q<T>(T t) where T : I
{
  t.M();
}
```

and

```
void Q<T>(T t) where T : I
{
  I i = t;
  i.M();
}
```

Are different! The former mutates `t` because the boxing is skipped. The latter boxes and then mutates the box.

The takeaway here should be **mutable value types are pure evil and you should avoid them at all costs**.  As we've seen, you can very easily get into situations where you think you should be mutating a copy, but you're mutating the original, or worse, situations where you think you are mutating an original, but you're mutating a copy.

> What bizarre magic makes this work?

Use sharplab.io and disassemble the methods I've given into IL. Read the IL very carefully; if there is anything you don't understand, look it up. All the magical mechanisms that make this optimization work are well-documented.

> Does the jitter always do this?

No! (As you would know if you read all the documentation as I just suggested.)

However, it is slightly tricky to construct a scenario where the optimization cannot be performed. I will leave that as a puzzle:

Write me a program where we have a struct type `S` that implements an interface `I`. We constrain type parameter `T` to `I`, and construct `T` with `S`, and pass in a `T t`. We call a method with `t`, as the receiver, and the jitter always causes the receiver to be boxed.

Hint: I predict that the called method's name has seven letters in it. Was I right?

Challenge #2: A question: Is it possible to also demonstrate that the boxing occurred using the same technique that I suggested before? (That technique being: show that a boxing must have occurred because a mutation happened to a copy, not to the original.

> Are there scenarios where the jitter boxes unnecessarily?

Yes! When I was working on the compiler, the jitter did not optimize away "box T to O, immediately unbox O back to T" instruction sequences, and sometimes the C# compiler is required to generate such sequences to make the verifier happy. We requested that the optimization be implemented; I do not know if it ever was.

> Can you give an example?

Sure. Suppose we have

```
class C<T>
{
  public virtual void M<U>(T t, U u) where U : T { }
}
class D : C<int>
{
  public override void M<U>(int t, U u)
  {
```

OK, now at this point you know that the only possible type for `U` is `int`, and so `t` should be assignable to `u`, and `u` should be assignable to `t`, right? But the CLR verifier does not see it that way, and you can then run into situations where the compiler must generate code that causes `int` to be boxed to `object` and then unboxed to `U`, which is `int`, so the round-trip is pointless.

> What's the takeaway here?

- Do not mutate value types.
- Generics are not templates. Overload resolution only happens once.
- The jitter works very hard to eliminate boxing in generics, but if a `T` is converted to `object`, then that `T` is really, truly converted to `object`.